# LESS CSS, nested selectors, and the quest to reduce CSS bloat

Tags: css, less

While I'm aware of [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) and its many ways to optimise my processed CSS, I'm trying to look for some fancy ways to reduce my CSS bloat within LESS itself and not have to rely on some magic behind someone else's post-jiggery-pokery on my CSS (autoprefixer is enough!).

I primarily use LESS CSS for my pre-processing, but I'm having a tricky time trying to figure out how to consolidate a number of selectors that also works with the nested inheritance. It's possible what I'm trying to do is completely out of LESS's scope, but I'm trying, gosh darn it.

My main example is when trying to iterate over a number of input element variants which share a similar look (e.g. `text`, `password`, `email`, `url`, `tel`, etc.). I then want to apply a ruleset to that consolidated selector which also contains  some `&` stuff (e.g. styling the input states like `:active` and `:hover`).

Here's my current state of experimentation ([view in codepen](http://codepen.io/lvl99/pen/qrdbxw)):

```
/*
 * Collect all the text inputs in a list to iterate over
 * (used in example 1 and 2)
 */
@text-inputs: text,
              number,
              email,
              tel,
              url,
              password,
              search,
              color,
              date,
              datetime,
              datetime-local,
              time,
              month,
              week;

/*
 * Collect all the text inputs in a single string
 * (no iteration needed; used in example 3)
 */
@all-text-inputs: ~'input[type=text],
                    input[type=number],
                    input[type=email],
                    input[type=tel],
                    input[type=url],
                    input[type=password],
                    input[type=search],
                    input[type=color],
                    input[type=date],
                    input[type=datetime],
                    input[type=datetime-local],
                    input[type=time],
                    input[type=month],
                    input[type=week]';

/*
 * Apply ruleset to all the text selectors (bloated)
 */
.text-inputs(@rules) {
  // Start the text input selector generation
  .-text-input(@i: length(@text-inputs)) when (@i > 0) {
    @text-input: extract(@text-inputs, @i);
    @selector: ~"input[type=@{text-input}]";

    @{selector} {
      @rules();
    }

    .-text-input((@i - 1));
  }

  .-text-input;
}

/*
 * Apply ruleset to all the text selectors in one consolidated selector
 */
.consolidate-text-inputs(@rules) {
  // Start the text input selector generation
  .-text-input(@i: length(@text-inputs)) when (@i > 0) {
    @text-input: extract(@text-inputs, @i);
    @selector: ~"input[type=@{text-input}]";
    .-text-input(@selector; (@i - 1));
  }

  // -- Append another text input selector
  .-text-input(@selector; @i) when (@i > 0) {
    @text-input: extract(@text-inputs, @i);
    @-selector: ~"@{selector}, input[type=@{text-input}]";
    .-text-input(@-selector; (@i - 1));
  }

  // -- Output the selector and the rules
  .-text-input(@selector; @i) when (@i = 0) {
    @{selector} {
      @rules();
    }
  }

  .-text-input;
}

// Works, but is bloated
.example-1 {
  .text-inputs({
    color: green;

    &:hover {
      background-color: yellow;
      color: blue;
    }

    &:focus,
    &:active {
      color: purple;
    }
  });
}

// Broken; overwrites all the other example CSS as well
.example-2 {
  .consolidate-text-inputs({
    color: red;

    &:hover {
      background-color: lightblue;
      color: purple;
    }

    &:focus,
    &:active {
      color: green;
    }
  });
}

// Broken; overwrites all the other examples as well
.example-3 {
  @{all-text-inputs} {
    color: orange;

    &:hover {
      background-color: lilac;
      color: blue;
    }

    &:focus,
    &:active {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Example 1 definitely works, however it's output is bloated (output has been simplified to illustrate bloat):

```
.example-1 input[type=text] {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=number] {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=email] {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=...] {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=text]:hover {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=number]:hover {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=email]:hover {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=...]:hover {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=text]:focus,
.example-1 input[type=text]:active {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=number]:focus,
.example-1 input[type=number]:active {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=email]:focus,
.example-1 input[type=email]:active {
  ...
}
.example-1 input[type=...]:focus,
.example-1 input[type=...]:active {
  ...
}
```

Example 2/3 are so broken that they affect all the other examples.

In a perfect implementation their output would be like (simplified to illustrate point):

```
.example-2 input[type=text],
.example-2 input[type=number],
.example-2 input[type=email],
.example-2 input[type=...] {
  ...
}

.example-2 input[type=text]:hover,
.example-2 input[type=number]:hover,
.example-2 input[type=email]:hover,
.example-2 input[type=...]:hover {
  ...
}

.example-2 input[type=text]:focus,
.example-2 input[type=text]:active,
.example-2 input[type=number]:focus,
.example-2 input[type=number]:active,
.example-2 input[type=email]:focus,
.example-2 input[type=email]:active,
.example-2 input[type=...]:focus,
.example-2 input[type=...]:active {
  ...
}
```

Anyone have any ideas exactly how that "perfect implementation" might be?

I prefer LESS to SCSS for 95% of things, but I find SCSS is a little friendlier for this kind of loop/nesting stuff.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [CSS optimizer](http://www.cssportal.com/css-optimize/). LESS et al. aren't designed for optimization. Would integrating optimization into the compiler really produce results that were any different than optimizing as a post-processing step?

Comment: My thoughts are that while I could use a CSS optimiser, ideally I'd be writing 99.9% optimised code using LESS (or other such CSS pre-processor language).

Comment: Your best bet with Less (as far as I am aware) would be to explicitly write a dummy selector (or one out of the list of selectors which you want to iterate over) and then extend this selector within the loop. [Here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/mWJaJg) is a demo of what I mean.

Comment: Genius, Harry. Are you able to formulate it as an answer that I can accept?

Comment: I've experimented with the `extend` functionality but it still doesn't seem to work 100% right. Maybe there's something I'm just not getting...

Comment: If you don't need to support IE, use [`:is`](https://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo) and you won't need to loop so much.